# shouldStartLoadwithRequest not getting called in subclass

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a view controlled app.  On my xib I have no webviews but I do have buttons that bring up classes that have webviews. So hit button one and a uiwebview pops up so on and so forth.

Now in one of my classes I pull up a remote webpage that has a link on it. I want to over-ride that button link with shouldStartLoadwithrequest.  How ever this never seems to get called.

Right now my class is called Tenth.m and I have this code in my view controller

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

NSLog(@" Test spot 1");
NSString* scheme = [[request URL] scheme];
if ([@"didTap" isEqual:scheme]) {
    // Call your method
     NSLog(@" Test spot 2");
    [self didTapButton1];
    return NO;
} else {
     NSLog(@" Test spot 3");
    return YES;
}}
```

But I get nothing (none of my NSLogs).  I have tried putting this into my Tenth.m class and still nothing.  I have looked at other examples and even downloaded one but it only uses the viewcontroller and delegates classes.  No third class.

I'm lost as to why its not getting called.

Here is my third class

```
#import "Tenth.h"


@implementation Tenth

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
[category10 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/api/didtap.php"]]];

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
 - (void)loadView
{
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return YES;
}

@end
```

remote page code

```
    <a href="didTap://button1">hello</a>
```

Tenth.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface Tenth : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {

IBOutlet UIWebView *category10;

}

-(IBAction)back;
@end
```

Comment: 1. You set your webview's delegate to `self`? 2. Shouldn't `[@"didTap" isEqual:scheme]` be `[@"didTap" isEqualToString:scheme]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first guess is that the Web view does not have its delegate set.  In order for it to call

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

The class containing this method needs to be set as the webview's delegate.  So somewhere in the code there should be a line similar to `webView.delegate = <variable>`, where the variable is the instance of the class which has implemented the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` method.

This is often "self" when the webView is a subview of a viewController's view.  But the way you have described your application, I am not sure if it will be self or not, but it sounds like it will not be self, but the name of the instance of a different class.

Comment: so what I can find is webview.delegate = self goes in the viewdidload of the Tenth.m file(see above).  but I then get the error: use of undeclared identifier "webView"

Comment: Ok, well, use the name of webView view variable, whatever it is called.

Comment: No laughing.  But where would I find that? In my viewcontoller I set iboutlet Tenth *tenth;   Is that what I'm looking for? If so it gives an error of Property delegate not found on object of type 'Tenth'

Comment: Well, it sounds like the webView is a part of some other class.  So it should be a property or an instance of that class.  So you will need to find wherever you see something in a ".h" that looks like this:

UIWebView *webView;

the part that says "webView" is the name of the variable, in your case it might be something other than "webView."  Whatever the name of the variable is, you will need to find it and set the delegate of the variable to whatever class has the shouldStartLoadingRequest: method.

Comment: ok In my Tenth.h file I set set UIWebview *category10; so now I put category10.delegate= self; in my didLoad of my Tenth.m file. And shouldStart.... still does not get called.  Does the shouldStartLoadWithRequest go into my viewcontroller, appdelegate, or Tenth.m file?  I have it in my viewcontroller.m file now.

Comment: I think you should try putting it in Tenth.m.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

  // Remember to set web view delegate to self.
  category10.delegate = self;
}
```